# prevent Android BootReceiver from starting main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, boot

Here´s my problem:

my Android app registers a boot receiver, which initializes a PushNotification-Manager (PushWoosh).
This is because even after a reboot of the device, the user should be able to receive push notifications without having to start the app manually.

This works, but when the device is rebooted, the apps main activity (MainMenuActivity) is launched and brought to the foreground, which should not happen.

Here´s the involved code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Re-register PushManagers after reboot -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application 
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

<!-- PushWoosh -->
<activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>
<activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>

<!-- PushWoosh -->
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="de.myapp.android"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- PushWoosh -->
<service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService"/>

<!-- Boot-Receiever -->
<receiver android:name="de.myapp.android.startup.BootCompleteReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="de.myapp.android.activity.MainMenuActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Starten bei Klick auf Launcher Icon -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Starten bei Erhalt einer Push Notification -->
        <action android:name="de.myapp.android.MESSAGE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

BootCompleteReceiver.java:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        PushWooshHelper.setupPushNotifications(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

}
```

PushWooshHelper.java:

```
public class PushWooshHelper {

    public static void setupPushNotifications(Context context) {
        PushManager pushManager = new PushManager(context, AppIDs.PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID, AppIDs.GCM_PROJECT_ID);
        pushManager.onStartup(context);
        pushManager.startTrackingGeoPushes();
    }

}
```

MainMenuActivity.java:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }


    private void checkMessage(Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null) {

            String log = "PUSH NOTIFICATION RECEIVED.";

            if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT)) {
                log += "message: " + intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT);
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT)) {
                log += "<register>";
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT)) {
                log += "<unregister>";
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT)) {
                log += "<register error>";
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT)) {
                log += "<unregister error>";
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        setIntent(intent);
        checkMessage(intent);

        setIntent(new Intent());
    }
}
```

Please note: I do not have access to PushManager.onStartup(), since it is provided by PushWoosh.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the 'de.myapp.android.MESSAGE'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange. Pushwoosh uses GCM which works after restart of the device out of the box. You just have to register for the push notifications once and then after restart GCM takes care about that itself.

Comment: You are right. I implemented the boot receiver because push notifications did not work after a reboot. But this was due to another error, so when set up properly, there´s really no need to instantiate the PushManager on each boot manually.